# XBRL parser either by JAXB or any other

Tags: xbrl

I have worked on JAXB parsing with a simple XML file, but with my new project I have an XBRL file which is used for business record and that needs to parse. Is there any parsing technique for XBRL files? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

XBRL is more than just an XML file. See my explanation in https://stackoverflow.com/a/38395549/2124628. Basically, it's a **very large** exercise to write an XBRL parser: You'd need to start with a parsing the XSD, Xlink and linkbase resources before you can even start parsing an XBRL file.

As I recommended in the other post: try leveraging an existing product, it's probably worth the investment.

Comment: Any further updates to this? Any open source parsers? Thx

Answer (score 1):

there is a python package which parses XBRL

`https://github.com/greedo/python-xbrl/`